# How long are LogCat entries kept in memory?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

After what time are LogCat logs erased from phone's memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't depend on time, but on the memory used.

You can know the size limit by using `adb logcat -g` (which usually returns a value between 64Kb and 512Kb).

Comment: FYI: You can increase the size of the log buffer by opening the Android Device: Settings -> Developer Options